# How to log full raw WCF client request from client side?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, soap-client, ws-security

I have a WCF client with TransportWithMessageCredential security mode. When try to log request using BeforeSendRequest

```
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    { 
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\tmp\\request_log.xml");
        file.WriteLine(request.ToString());
        file.Close();

        return null;
    }
```

have result without security tags

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">https://(skiped)</Action>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
    ...
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

How can I log full raw request in client? It must be like this

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
<u:Created>...</u:Created>
<u:Expires>..</u:Expires>
</u:Timestamp>
<o:BinarySecurityToken>
<!-- Removed-->
</o:BinarySecurityToken>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
...
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
...
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</o:Security>
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">skiped</Action>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
...
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

UPD. Security options for binding

```
 <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
      realm="" />
   <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Basic256" />
 </security>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't found how to do this in C# but had captured raw request using
[Charles SSL proxying](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/)

The request contains all security tags.

The article which helped me so much [Tracing-WCF-Messages](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/Dec/09/Tracing-WCF-Messages)

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/880445/Logging-SOAP-web-service-envelop-request-and-reply) may help:

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);        
    Log("Request:" + Environment.NewLine + buffer.CreateMessage());
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The same result. Only <Action> tag in <s:Header>, no security tags

Comment: The result shows that you don't have security in soup header!

Comment: You may check if you have correctly added security options.

Comment: Maybe something wrong with options but I have success answer from server using my app.config description. Added security options for binding in question. Doesn't it mean that transport must be https and the message must be signed with certificate?

Comment: HTTPS is a transport layer security not an application layer security protocol . It means the message body will not be changed where you are logging it. It will be encrypted in TCP layer handled by your web-server out of your application, you are logging the message in your application. So to see the encrypted packets you need a tool to trace packets in network physical layer like wireShark.

Comment: WSHttpBinding is a message level security. that has its [own story](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) which is free.
If your endpoint is https be sure to bypass certificate validation with this

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate {return true;};
```

because Fiddler uses its own certificate that is invalid for your connection.